# Atrapar respuesta xml y convertirla a JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angular, xml

Me encuentro interactuando con un web service el cual realizo una petición de tipo POST y me retorna un status 200 y un archivo xml , pero cuando quiero atrapar esta respuesta me retorna el error:  "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse () at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad".
Quisiera encontrar la manera de atrapar la respuesta sin que me retorne error.

servicio:

```
emision(body): Observable<any> {
    let httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        
        'Authorization': "*********",
        'Action': "postproduct",
       
      })
    };
    return this.http.post('/api/******',
      body, httpOptions)
}
```

subscribe:

```
 this.mainService.emision(obj).subscribe(
                  (value) => {
                    console.log(value);
                   
                  },
                  (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                    console.warn(
                      "ERROR CONEXION"
                    );
                  }
);
```

Comment: Por defecto el `http` de angular intentará parsear todo lo que obtenga como JSON. Prueba a añadir `responseType: 'text'` en las opciones. Por supuesto luego tendrás que parsear el XML, porque te lo obtendrá como texto

Comment: Tu me dices que haga esto?? ```headers: new HttpHeaders({
        
        'Authorization': "Basic YWdlbmNpYXRlc3QyMDIwOnQzc3Q1NDhzZGYyZTFmZw==",
        'Action': "get_currencies",
        'Cookie': "API=f17bba267f741cf78a04578832c73ac6",
        'responseType': 'text',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
      })```   luego debo parsear la respuesta en el subscribe o en el mismo observable con un map?

Comment: No en los headers, en las opciones.

Answer (score 0):

La solución a tu problema es el ejemplo que pongo abajo, como comenta el otro amigo en tu ejemplo de abajo lo esta agregando a los headers no en las opciones deberías tener algo similar a esto espero te ayude :)

responseType': "text"

Solución:

```
emision(body): Observable<any> {
    const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Authorization': '*********',
            'Action': 'postproduct'
            }),
            responseType: 'text'
    };
        return this.http.post('/api/******', body, httpOptions);
}
```

Igualmente te dejo un post donde tienen el mismo problema al tuyo saludos :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45276250/angular-4-httpclient-xml-response